# One loading screen for multiple React Apollo queries

Tags: reactjs, react-native, apollo, react-apollo

I'm working on a React Native application with Apollo 2.1.  So far, everything has come together really nicely.

I have a top level component that allows users to flip through pages of data.  That component is agnostic with regard to the data being viewed.

It looks something like this:

```
<Query query={GET_AUTHORS}>
  {(loading, errors, data) =>
    <CategoryPager categories={data.authors}>
      {(author) => <AuthorDetails author={author} />}
    </CategoryPager>
  }
</Query>
```

Author details would execute queries to retrieve the details relevant for its own display.  The advantage is I can build some common components and reuse them:

```
<Query query={GET_ARTICLES}>
  {(loading, errors, data) =>
    <CategoryPager categories={data.articles}>
      {(articles) => <ArticleDetails article={article} />}
    </CategoryPager>
  }
</Query>
```

This is a very simplified (and somewhat pseudocoded) example, but in our more complicated scenario, this composition has been pretty awesome.  The problem is, now I'd like to have a top level display when any of the queries are loading (or if one of them has an error).

That is, I'd like to show "this screen is loading," or "this screen has encountered an error; click here to try again."

I've struggled to find examples of other people doing this.  What's a good way to have a top level component be aware of the loading status of lower level queries, preferably keeping things as loosely coupled as possible?

One thing I tried (that I didn't think through all that well) was that I could use a context to keep track of some top level state.  Then, when the queries change states, they can inform the stack of queries through that context.  However, you can't change state during a state transition.  The query component exposes the `onCompleted` and `onError`, but no `onStarted` or `onNetworkStatusChanged` events.

Comment: By querying you mean a network call?

Comment: @10101010 I do. Yes.